# $L$ is regular. Show that $Root(L) $ is also regular

Tags: regular-language

Let $Root(L)=\{w \mid \exists {n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ such that } w^n\in L\}$.
How to deal with it ? I tried think about modifications connected with automat for $L$, but it failed. Help me, please.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a regular language. Then there is a surjective monoid morphism $f:A^* \to M$ and a subset $P$ of $M$ such that $f^{-1}(P) = L$. I claim that $Root(L) = f^{-1}(Q)$ where 
$$
Q = \{m \in M \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } u^n \in P \}
$$
Thus $L'$ is recognized by the finite monoid $M$ and hence is regular.

**Proof of the claim**.
\begin{align*}
  f^{-1}(Q) &= \{u \in A^* \mid f(u) \in Q \} \\
  &= \{u \in A^* \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f(u)^n \in P  \} \\
  &= \{u \in A^* \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f(u^n) \in P  \} \\  
  &= \{u \in A^* \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } u^n \in f^{-1}(P)  \} \\  
  &= \{u \in A^* \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } u^n \in L  \} \\
  &= L'
\end{align*}

Comment: Is it possible to solve it without monoids ?

Comment: Yes, see @YuvalFilmus [answer's to a similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29783/9612)

Comment: I don't know if I correctly understand: He consider language $$\{x:\exists a,b \text  { such that }|a|=p|x|\wedge |b|=q|x|
 \wedge axb\in L \}$$